# How to get github action jobId

Tags: github-actions

I want to get the exact jobId in the job I defined, but I use ${{github.job}} to get the name (deploy job).
The exact address is this: https://github.com/xxxxx/my-repo/actions/runs/5888912298/job/15971069222

my code: ([https://github.com/${owner}/${repo}/actions/runs/${context.runId}/job/${{github.job}}](https://github.com/$%7Bowner%7D/$%7Brepo%7D/actions/runs/$%7Bcontext.runId%7D/job/$%7B%7Bgithub.job%7D%7D))`

Get the exact jobId

Comment: 15971069222,Is this a random jobId or an accurate jobId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub doesn't official support retrieving `Job ID` from inside the job at the moment.

But this is available as an api response from:
`https://api.github.com/repos/$REPOSITORY/actions/runs/$RUN_ID/jobs`

So you can have a step like:

```
job_url="https://api.github.com/repos/$REPOSITORY/actions/runs/$RUN_ID/jobs"
job_id=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: token ${{ env.token }}" $job_url | jq -r '.jobs[] | .id')
```

Notes:

1. You can retrieve the `RUN_ID` using `${{ github.run_id }}`.
2. You need to install `jq` to be able to parse the JSON response.